# Four divs positioning: 2 on sides, 2 in the middle

Tags: css, html

I want to arrange 4 divs' position, 2 on sides and 2 in the middle.

like:

```
         |  div middle top  |
div left |                  | div right
         |  div middle down |
```

Using CSS, is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Used to this**

**HTml**

```
<div class="parent">

    <div class="pull-left">left</div>

    <div class="pull-right">Right</div>

    <div class="centerDiv">
        <div class="topDiv">Top Div</div>
        <div class="bottomDiv">bottom div </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
html,body{height:100%;}

.parent{overflow:hidden;
border:solid 1px red; margin:0 auto;width:600px;height:100%;}
.pull-left{
    width:25%;float:left;
}
.pull-right{width:25%;float:right;}
.centerDiv{margin:0 25%;position:relative; height:100%;}
.topDiv{position: absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;}
.bottomDiv{position: absolute;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KK6qd/)**

Answer (score 0):

Check it this, you can check live demo: http://cssdesk.com/2JEQA

HTML

```
<div id="left"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
      <div id="middle_top"></div>
      <div id="middle_botton"></div>
</div>

<div id="right"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#left {
    float:left;
}

.wrapper{
   float:left;
}


#right {
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is the same as Rohit Azad answer, I just added height and background color so that you could see it clearly. If you want this I would be happy if you give the credit to him. :)

HTML

```
    <div class="pull-left">left</div>

    <div class="pull-right">Right</div>

    <div class="centerDiv">
        <div class="topDiv">Top Div</div>
        <div class="bottomDiv">bottom div </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,body{height:100%;}

.parent{
overflow:hidden;
border:solid 1px red; 
margin:0 auto;
width:600px;
height:100%;
}

.pull-left{
width:25%;
float:left;
background-color:red;
height:100%;
}

.pull-right{
width:25%;
float:right;
background-color:blue; 
height:100%;
}

.centerDiv{
margin:0 25%;
position:relative; 
height:100%;
}

.topDiv{
position: absolute;
top:0;left:0;
right:0;
background-color:yellow;
height:50%;
}

.bottomDiv{
position: absolute;
bottom:0;left:0;
right:0;
background-color:green;
height:50%;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/N3qmH/6/)

Comment: thanks for all your help. but what i actually wondering is if there's anyway to modify four divs. if you put the middle two divs inside of another div. what u actually do is back to modifying 3 divs. so i guess it turns out there is no way to modify 4 divs' positions. but thanks again for your help.